# Python read specific line and only 5 linese after that keyword

Tags: python

I would like to extract specific lines from text file using python. I would like to extract line starting with neighbor and 5 lines after that.

Comment: Can you add to your question sample input/expected output + what have you done so far?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if line.startswith('neighbor'):`?

Comment: You were asked for code with expected input and output. This helps us understand the question and gives a basis for writing an answer. In my proposed answer below, I posted a full functional program. Regardless of whether you like the answer or accept it, it demonstrates the kind of thing that should be in questions.

Comment: `with open('file.txt','r') as f:` `for i,line in enumerate(f):` `if line.startswith('neighboor'):` `lst = [lst[n] for n in range(i,5+1)]` `break`

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way to do it with reads the file line by line, which may be more efficient than read the whole file at once if the file is large.

```py
count = 0
keyword_found = False

with open("file.txt") as file:
    next_line = True
    while next_line:
        next_line = file.readline()
        
        if next_line.startswith("neighbor"):
            keyword_found = True

        if keyword_found:
            count += 1

        if next_line and count > 5:
            print(next_line)
```

EDIT:
To go back `number_lines_back` when keyword is found and print `number_lines_total` lines in total:

```py
number_lines_back = 3
number_lines_total = 7
keyword_found = False
prev_lines = [0] * number_lines_back

with open("file.txt") as file:
    next_line = True
    while next_line:
        next_line = file.readline()
        
        if next_line.startswith("neighbor"):
            keyword_found = True
            
            for line in prev_lines:
                print(line)

            lines_to_print = number_lines_total - number_lines_back
        else:
            prev_lines.pop(0)
            prev_lines.append(next_line)

        if keyword_found:
            lines_to_print -= 1
            
        if next_line and lines_to_print >= 0:
            print(next_line)
        else:
            break
```

NOTE: `number_lines_back` should not be to big otherwise the `prev_lines` list gets too big. Also this will only work when only 1 line in the file starts with the word "neighbor", so if the output is not as expected maybe that is the cause.

Comment: Bram Dekker: you did it. There was a slight typo instead of line it is line_next but it did work for me. Thank you. Can you please suggest a resource to learn python

Comment: If I want to change it a bit. Lets say if i find keyword I would like to go three lines back and read next 7 lines ??

Comment: @NyleIc Oh yeah, you're right. I edited the post. For basic's a book like [https://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.pdf](https://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.pdf) can be helpful. For specific algorithms or info about specific functions, [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org) and [Tutorialspoints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm) are nice websites. And of course, Stackoverflow if you run into any problems! Good luck learning Python!

Comment: @NyleIc - This program finds "neighbor", skips 5 lines, and then prints the rest of the file. If you want to go back 3 lines, then skip 7 lines, then print, isn't that the same as just skipping 4 lines ahead?

Comment: @Bram Dekker What I want to do is find neighbor and go back three lines. Once I am back three lines I would like to start reading and count up to 7 lines. So find keyword go back three lines read from that point till line count is 7

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` can help. `dropwhile` will drop lines until a condition is met, so it can be set to start taking lines when "neighbor" is seen. `islice` will take a given number of items (its like list slicing, but as a function so can be used with other iterators). Put it all together and

```
import itertools

def foo(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        return list(itertools.islice(
            itertools.dropwhile(lambda l: not l.startswith("neighbor"), fp),
            0, 6))

# test
with open("mytestfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(6):
        f.write(f"this is pre line {i}\n")
    f.write("neighbor line here\n")
    for i in range(20):
        f.write(f"this is post line {i}\n")

mylist = foo("mytestfile.txt")
print("".join(mylist))
```

If the nested tools are confusing, you can always pull the inner iterator out into its own variable

```
def foo(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        dropper = itertools.dropwhile(
            lambda l: not l.startswith("neighbor"), fp)
        return list(itertools.islice(dropper, 0, 6))
```